# SCSS file error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, import, sass

I am trying to set up a site ran on Jekyll I haven't updated in awhile (obviously my developer skills are very rusty in general) with Github Pages. Whenever I try, I get this error:
 Your site is having problems building: Your SCSS file sass/about.scss has an error on line 1: File to import not found or unreadable: default. Load paths: _sass /hoosegow/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/minima-2.1.1/_sass. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-invalid-sass-or-scss/.

All my scss pages like about.scss start with this:

```
---
---

@import "default";
```

or

```
---
---

@import "bootstrap";
```

I have made sure that my config.yml file has this:

```
sass:
  sass_dir: ./_sass
```

and I am not sure what to do from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a pretty big hint!

> File to import not found or unreadable: default

It's looking for a file called `default.scss` and is unable to do so. Make sure the file exists in the `sass_dir` you configured and doesn't have any weird read-permissions on it (e.g. can you open the file in another program?).

Comment: Thank you! I'm obviously braindead - I just needed to reinstall bootstrap by copying the correct directory and files into my code, as they went missing for some reason. I followed this guide http://veithen.github.io/2015/03/26/jekyll-bootstrap.html and it worked just fine. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this error by creating the *imported* stylesheets (eg. _scss/_default.scss) using **cmd**.

For example: **NUL > _default.scss**

Be careful not to overwrite any existing files.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the file name.
For Example: if your file name is
navbar.scss
then change it to _navbar.scss
and import will remain the same as => @import './styles/navbar'; (assuming the scss file is in your styles folder)

Don't forget to restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub ACTIONS CI has thrown this error.

I found that I did not add `webpack-dev-server`.

I added it as follows and it helped:

```
    - name: Add webpack-dev-server
      run: |
        yarn add webpack-dev-server
    - name: Build App
      ...
```